# Get the HTML of a site

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi

I'm trying to get into a string (or a char[]) the html of a page...( and such)
I know how to use basic sockets, and connect as a client/server...

I've wrote a client in the past, that gets an ip & port, and connects to it, and send images and such using sockets betwen the client & the server...

I've searched the internet a bit, and found I can connect to the website, and send a GET request, to get the HTTP content of a page and store it in a variable, though I have a few problems :

1) I'm trying to get the HTML of a page that isnt the main page of a site, like, not stackoverflow.com, but stackoverflow.com/help and such (not the "official page of the site", but something inside that site)

2) I'm not sure how to either send or store the data I got from the GET request...

I saw there are outside libraries I could use, but I rather use sockets only...

By the way - I'm using Windows 7, and I aim that it'll work on Windows only(so it's fine if it wont work for Linux)

Thanks for you'r help! :)

Comment: IF you want to use third party code than try this out http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2425/Get-The-HTML-Source-of-Any-Web-Page

Comment: The HTTP protocol seems pretty straightforward at first glance, but it has many gotchas. I would strongly advise you against trying to implement it manually. You should really use an existing library.

Comment: how do you want to code it tell me that so can tell you more specifically..

Comment: @spt025 How does ASP have anything to do with C++?

Comment: ohk check this out...Pure C++
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/windows/17264/

Comment: @spt025 Yeah and it doesn't handle separation of headers and content, footers, chunked responses, keep-alive and what not. Again, better use an existing, feature-complete library rather than some incomplete bits of code that will fail at the first occasion.

Comment: Yup but he's asking just a simple code to do so...nothing high-figh so this should do for him ..

Comment: @spt025 Which is exactly why I'm saying that simple code won't cut it: the server that answers the request will be a full HTTP implementation and can use any HTTP feature, so the client has to implement those features too if he wants to understand the response. And there are just too many HTTP features to reasonably hope implementing them manually (unless you dedicate yourself to writing a full HTTP client implementation, but that's a whole other matter). Been there, done that. A feature-complete library is the only real solution.

Comment: It's the same kind of problem as parsing XML or HTML: you may think that you can get away with regexes but as soon as the document starts being a bit complex, all hell breaks loose; a fully-fledged parser is the only real solution too. In other words: why waste time reinventing inadequate square wheels when there are perfectly working round ones already available?

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Comment: calling something an "internet page" doesn't lend much optimism that we're going to be able to help you.

Comment: @xaxxon haha I wrote the question at 3 AM XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access a resource on some host you just specify the path to the resource in the first line of the request, just after the 'GET'. E.g. check http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#http1.1

```
GET /path/file.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.host1.com:80
[blank line here]
```

I'd also recomend using some portable library like Boost.ASIO instead of sockets. But I'd strongly recomend you to use some existing, portable library implementing HTTP protocol. Of course only if it is not a matter of learning how to implement it.

Even if you want to implement it by yourself it'd be worth knowing the existing solutions. For instance this is how you can get a webpage using cpp-netlib (http://cpp-netlib.org/0.10.1/index.html):

```
using namespace boost::network;
using namespace boost::network::http;

client::request request_("http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
request_ << header("Connection", "close");
client client_;
client::response response_ = client_.get(request_);
std::string body_ = body(response_);
```

This is how you can do it using cURL library (http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simple.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com");
        /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

        /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        /* Check for errors */ 
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        /* always cleanup */ 
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Both libraries are portable but if you'd like to use some Windows-specific API you might check WinINet (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383630%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it's less pleasant to use.

Comment: I dont want to use other libraries, because when I used OpenCV, I had to copy 2 DLLS to whenever the EXE were, and it is pretty annoying...
Portable libraries arel like, libraries I only have to include, but dont act regulary as normal .h files or something ?

Comment: I've tried to get the HTML of the about page :
This is the get I'm sending, though it does not work :
`"GET /about / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:stackoverflow.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";`

Comment: Boost.ASIO is header-only library, and this is an example of HTTP synchronious client: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/sync_client.cpp.

Comment: As for the request, you should probably send `GET /about HTTP/1.1 [...]` without the additional `/` which is the path to the main page.